# Wrong bits in Serial Connection reset

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication

I Created a server/client JAVA application that sends and receives file using Serial Communication (RXTXComm Library).
Due to my project, the link can be physically cut off in the middle of transmission, so I implemented a sliding window and a connection reset code that supposedly resume the transmission after the network has been reestablished.

The Problem is, the data received after the connection had be cut off and reestablished is corrupted

Server Code "Receiver":

```
bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
System.out.println("R\t Bytes read\t" + bytesRead);
current = bytesRead;
System.out.println("R\t\t FIRST Last byte recieved \t" + current);
outR.writeLong((current + 1));
outR.flush();
System.out.println("R\t\tSending ACK");

while (true) {
    do {
        bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
        System.out.println("R\t Bytes read\t" + bytesRead);
        if (bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
        System.out.println("R\t\tLast byte recieved \t" + current);
        //ACK = Integer.toString((current+1));
        outR.writeLong((current + 1));

        outR.flush();
        System.out.println("R\t\tSending ACK");

    } while (bytesRead > 0);
    //in.close();

    if ((mybytearray[current - 1] & 0xff) != 0b01000101) {
        int timer = 0;
        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            timer++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (timer > 5) {

                System.out.println("R\t\t Connection Timeout");
                timer = 0;
                current = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current - 1);
bos.flush();
System.out.println("R\t\tfinished recieving");
bos.close();
```

and this is the client "Sender"

```
public static class InReciever implements Runnable {
    DataInputStream inS;
    public InReciever(DataInputStream in) {
        inS = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //int timer=0;
            while (true) {
                long ack = 0;

                if (brek)
                    break;
                if ((ack = inS.readLong()) > 0) {

                    firstACK = false;
                    windowStart = ack;

                    System.out.println("S\t\tRecieving ack");
                    System.out.println("S\tNext byte to send\t" + ack);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {
    OutputStream out;
    DataInputStream inS;
    DataOutputStream outHello;
    byte[] mybytearray;

    public SerialWriter(OutputStream out, DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream outHello, byte[] buffer) {
        this.out = out;
        inS = in;
        this.outHello = outHello;
        mybytearray = buffer;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            new Thread(new InReciever(inS)).start();
            for (int i = 0; i < mybytearray.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println("windowEnd \t"+windowEnd);
                out.write(mybytearray[i]);
                out.flush();
                int timer = 0;
                while (windowEnd > (windowStart + 2000) && !firstACK) {
                    timer++;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    if (timer > 5) {
                        System.out.println("S\tTimeout \n Restart connection \t");
                        i = -1;
                        out.flush();
                        windowStart = 0;
                        windowEnd = 0;
                        firstACK = true;
                    }
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                    //
                }
                windowEnd++;
            }
            outHello.writeChar('E');
            outHello.flush();
            System.out.println("s\tfinished sending");
            brek = true;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't analyzed each line of code but what I'm not seeing is any form of validation.  Serial communications usually employ many forms of validation such as packet checking.

Have you tried breaking the stream into smaller chunks and sending a chunk at a time?  The sender should include some type of CRC checksum calculation with each chunk that the receiver could verify.

After an interruption is restarted, the receiver would validate the most recent chunk with the CRC checksum.  If it does not match, then discard the chunk and restart where it left off.

My suspicion is that your "restart" code doesn't discard the corrupt bits properly.